# Unity 2021.3.10f1 - Ctrl+Z causing the UNITY to crash always

Tags: unity-game-engine

any advice how to eliminate this problem on this version? or any other advice?
Thank you.

Sometimes when I'm in the zone.. I forgot to remind myself not to ctrl+z while in the editor view of unity and worst case is every time it crashes it doesn't save my changes or update in the past 40mins-1hr work.

additional info: I am required to use the stated version.

update: as of the moment(12/4/2022), this issue is gone. I don't know how or why. I can do ctrl+z now in the editor mode.

Comment: Did you report it to unity?

Comment: I have the same issue in this version of unity.  Switched back to 2020.3f (never crashes).  Since you cannot switch versions, I suggest saving aggressively.

Comment: Yes, already did @BugFinder

Comment: that leaves me no choice then.. thanks for the feedbacks @hijinxbassist

Comment: update: as of the moment, this issue is gone. I don't know how or why. I can do ctrl+z now in the editor mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a very isolated issue. I looked up crash reports and can only find it for older versions. I think that a clean reinstall would be your best bet but I 'am guessing you already tried that. Here are the only bug reports I found:

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/prefabs-and-undo-leads-to-crash

it is only on versions: (2017.2.0b3, 2017.1.0p1, 5.6.2p4, 5.5.4p2)

Comment: Yes I already did , reinstall still the same... @hijinxbassist also has a problem maybe a minority has experience this as well? I appreciate the feedback.